# print all elements of a database, transformed to a python list in HTML using Flask without hardcodeing values

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to print all of the database entries in a table (`teams`) to an `.html` file and later apply custom formatting.

For the database, I have a database table called `Teams`, which has columns for `TEAM_NAME` and `COUNTRY`

In my Flask app I have the following app route and function:

```
    # views.py
    @app.route('/test')
    def test_route():

        conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("select * from Teams") # get db entries

        teams = [] # init list
        i = 0
        while True:
            res = c.fetchone() # get row
            if res is None:
                break
            else:
                teams.append(res) # add row to teams list
            i += 1

        return render_template('test.html', teams=teams)
```

Then I have the `test.html` file. In there, I want to be able to print all the database entries in separate paragraphs. To do this, I can hardcode them like this:

```
    <body>
        <p>{{teams[0]}}</p>
        <p>{{teams[1]}}</p>
        <p>{{teams[2]}}</p>
        <p>{{teams[3]}}</p>
        <p>{{teams[4]}}</p>
        <p>{{teams[5]}}</p>

    </body>
```

**How can I print all the teams withоut having to hardcode their id?**

Comment: With a `{% for %}` loop?

Comment: Your `i` variable is useless, you don't need counting - you're not using the counter for anything

Comment: @nosklo, yes, you are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
    {% for team in teams %}
    <p>{{team}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Check [jinja documentation here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) for what you can do on HTML templates